# How to access a control after Edit is clicked in asp:datagrid editcommand

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I need to access a label control after the edit is clicked to bindgrid based on the label text. How do I do that?

```
Private Sub ActionItems_EditCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles ActionItems.EditCommand
    ActionItems.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
    Dim fieldtypelbl As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblrcause")
    FillActions(fieldtypelbl.text)
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Code looks fine, just don't forget to cast control you found to Label type

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same by using
source.Parent.fieldname

as the datagrid is a part of the control being called on the same page multiple times